# invalid use of incomlete type 'ui:***'

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно сделать базовый класс `BaseWidget`, который содержит в себе базовый `ui` и наследоваться от него другими классами, которые будут использовать его `ui` и, вероятно, дополнять.
Во имя инкапсуляции решил сделать методы для получения указателя на `ui`.
При использовании его внутри класса `BaseWidget` проблем не возникает, но при попытке доступа через геттер получаю следующую ошибку:

```
*/mainwidget.cpp: In constructor ‘MainWidget::MainWidget(QSqlTableModel*, QWidget*)’:
*/mainwidget.cpp:15:17: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Ui::BaseTableWidget’
     connect(ui()->addButton,      &QPushButton::clicked,
                 ^
In file included from */mainwidget.h:5:0,
                 from */mainwidget.cpp:1:
*/basetablewidget.h:12:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Ui::BaseTableWidget’
 class BaseTableWidget;
```

---

```
// mainwidget.cpp
MainWidget::MainWidget(QSqlTableModel* m, QWidget *parent) :
    BaseTableWidget(m, headers, parent)
{    
    connect(ui()->addButton,      &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, &MainWidget::addClient);
    ***
}
```

---

```
// basewidget.h
namespace Ui {
class BaseTableWidget;
}

class BaseTableWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BaseTableWidget(QSqlTableModel *model, const QStringList& headers,
                             QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~BaseTableWidget();

    Ui::BaseTableWidget*    ui()                { return _ui; }

    ***

private:
    Ui::BaseTableWidget*    _ui;

    ***
}
```

---

```
#include "basetablewidget.h"
#include "ui_basetablewidget.h"

BaseTableWidget::BaseTableWidget(QSqlTableModel* m, const QStringList &headers,
                                 QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    _ui(new Ui::BaseTableWidget)
{
    _ui->setupUi(this);

    ***

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Везде где вы используете `ui` нужно подключать `#include "ui_basetablewidget.h"`. Так как именно там находится его полное объявление. В `basewidget.h` находится только forward declaration:

```
namespace Ui {
class BaseTableWidget;
}
```

Однако я бы все же посоветовал вам не обращаться к виджетам напрямую через `ui`. Если вы решите изменить внешний вид `BaseTableWidget` или отказаться от `_ui`, то вам придется вносить изменения во всей программе. По сути вы только создаете видимость инкапсуляции, теряя все ее преимущества. Лучше будет сделать методы, которые будут манипулировать `_ui`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
public:  
    void setAge(int age){
        _ui->ageInput->setValue(age);
    }
    int age() const{
        return _ui->ageInput->value();
    }
    void setName(const QString &name){
        _ui->nameInput->setText(name);
    }
    QString name() const{
        _ui->nameInput->text();
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
};
```